# Android:shape integer type is not allowed

Tags: android, android-studio, decompiling

I decompiled an APK (**disclaimer:** for personal use, not doing anything illegal) and aside from some weird `unknown_attr` values some attributes such as `layout_width`, `layout_height` and `android:shape` have integers as values.

Such as: `<shape android:shape="0"></shape>` or `android:layout_width="-1"`

When building an APK however, the android studio is throwing errors that integer types are not allowed.

Why is it that the decompiled APK **can** have integer types, but when re-compiling an APK it suddenly **can't**?

Do I have something misconfigured in my settings?

Comment: "Why is it that the decompiled APK can have integer types" -- my guess is that you are misinterpreting the output of your decompiler, and that those are references to resources (`android:layout_width`, `android:layout_height`) or an incomplete decompilation of a value back to the enumeration (`android:shape`). But, since you elected not to provide a [mcve], it will be difficult to confirm this.

Comment: @commonsWare I added an example of what it looks like, altough I'm not sure that's really going to help here. Either way, there is no misconfiguration in my studio settings that (when fixed) would allow me to build an APK with those integer values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no misconfiguration in my studio settings that (when fixed) would allow me to build an APK with those integer values?

No. That is an invalid `ShapeDrawable` resource, as you can tell by reading [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape).

Your problem lies in your decompiler.

Comment: Thanks, at least now I know where to look :)

Comment: @xorinzor: What you will be looking for is a decompiler that turns those integers into symbols (e.g., `oval` for `android:shape`, `match_parent` for `android:layout_width`) or references to resources. The *compiled* resources have those as integers; whatever decompiler you are using is not attempting to reverse those into valid resource source files.

Comment: I tried the online APK decompiler, which returned a lot of scrambled results and those integer types. After trying to decompile it manually, using a tutorial found on SO I got more usable code. Thanks :)